# How to center a span with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How to center a span with Twitter Bootstrap?

I've made a picture on Paint so it is simpler to understand what I want :

http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/888331prob.png

So what I would like to do is to center my div into each span. Spans contains dynamic text, so I cannot set a width and an `margin: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6" >
        <div class="span2 offset2" style="border:2px solid;">some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="span2 offset2"  style="border:2px solid;">some text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```